# SQL Server 2005 Function Create Temp Table of Date Ranges with Week Number

Tags: sql-server, function, lookup-tables, week-number

I have a function that I developed to return the week number of a date passed in from a query; the week numbers are custom to us and not any fixed standard week ranges. The function takes the date passed in and checks it against a range of dates created in a temp table within function, these date ranges are determined by a week number associated to a certain range of dates, it then returns the associated week number of the date.

Initially I was looking to create the week number look up range using the previous Saturday date as reference - most recent from date function is run - as the date to count 4 weeks back and create the look up. This worked fine but I now want to modify this and make it more dynamic.

I want to be able to pass in the same date as before but also want to pass in the number of look up weeks I want and also want to pass in the day name of the day to be used as last day in look up. So for example I pass in (Column.date,5,'Saturday')

This would give me 5 rows in temp table with range like this:

```
Week   first_date   Last_Date   
====   ==========   ==========
 1     22/06/2014   28/06/2014
 2     29/06/2014   05/07/2014
 3     06/07/2014   12/07/2014
 4     13/07/2014   19/07/2014 
 5     20/07/2014   26/07/2014
```

Sunday - Saturday being the range of dates, where the 26/07/2014 date is the last saturday before the date the function was run. If I was to change the day passed in to 'Sunday' then would obviously want range to change to Monday to Sunday date range:

```
Week   first_date   Last_Date   
====   ==========   ==========
 1     23/06/2014   29/06/2014
 2     30/06/2014   06/07/2014
 3     07/07/2014   13/07/2014
 4     14/07/2014   20/07/2014 
 5     21/07/2014   27/07/2014
```

The current function is fixed to only return range for up to last Saturday but am not sure how to make a dynamic date statement that works off of new parameters passed into function, which I have declared in the function but am not using yet. Function is below:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[daterangeweeknumber]
(
-- Add the parameters for the function here

@refDate datetime,
@NoWeeksforRange INT, -- New variable not yet used
@dayName Varchar(30)  -- New variable not yet used

)

RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN



-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @weeknumber INT
--declare other variables here
DECLARE @mytemptablevariable table (weeknumber INT,fromdate DATETIME,todate DATETIME)
DECLARE @lastsaturdaydate DATETIME

--Set last day date value using dayname value passed in. 
set @lastsaturdaydate = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '18991230', GETDATE()) / 7 * 7,  '18991230')

-- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
INSERT INTO @mytemptablevariable 
values (1, DATEADD(DAY, -27, @lastsaturdaydate), DATEADD(DAY, -21, @lastsaturdaydate))
INSERT INTO @mytemptablevariable 
values (2, DATEADD(DAY, -20, @lastsaturdaydate), DATEADD(DAY, -14, @lastsaturdaydate))
INSERT INTO @mytemptablevariable 
values (3, DATEADD(DAY, -13, @lastsaturdaydate), DATEADD(DAY, -07, @lastsaturdaydate))
INSERT INTO @mytemptablevariable 
values (4, DATEADD(DAY, -6, @lastsaturdaydate), @lastsaturdaydate)

select @weeknumber = weeknumber
from @mytemptablevariable
where @refdate >= fromdate AND @refdate <= todate

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @weeknumber

END
```

Any feedback on how to determine work I need to do to make this more dynamic would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Andrew

Edit:

This is the function that was create for this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[daterangeweeknumber]
(
-- Add the parameters for the function here

@refDate datetime,
@Weeks INT,
@day_parameter varchar(4)

)

--Define what data type the function returns
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

--Declare variables to be used in function

DECLARE @weeknumber INT
DECLARE @mytemptablevariable table (weeknumber INT,fromdate DATETIME,todate DATETIME)
DECLARE @i INT  
DECLARE @result_date as datetime
DECLARE @offset_day as int
DECLARE @weekfromdatedays INT
DECLARE @weektodatedays INT
DECLARE @today AS datetime 

--Set any predefined variable values 
--Make days number negative value
--Multiply weeks variable number by 7 to get number of days to end of first week in range
--Multiply weeks variable number by 7 and then substract 7 to get number of days to start of first week in range

set @today = DateAdd(Day, Datediff(Day,0, GetDate()), 0)
set @i = 1
set @weekfromdatedays = -(@Weeks * 7)
set @weektodatedays = -((@Weeks * 7)-7)

--Set the integer value of the offest day variable

SET  @offset_day =  CASE @day_parameter WHEN 'Sun' THEN 1
                                        WHEN 'Mon' THEN 2
                                        WHEN 'Tue' THEN 3
                                        WHEN 'Wed' THEN 4
                                        WHEN 'Thu' THEN 5
                                        WHEN 'Fri' THEN 6
                                        WHEN 'Sat' THEN 7
                END

--Using offset day work out the last day date value to take the range of weeks up to

SET @result_date = DATEADD(d,0-CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday,@today) = @offset_day THEN 7
                               WHEN DATEPART(weekday,@today) > @offset_day THEN DATEPART(weekday,@today) - @offset_day 
                               ELSE DATEPART(weekday,@today) - @offset_day + 7
                          END,
                          @today)

-- Run while loop to populate table

while (@i <= @Weeks)
    begin
        INSERT INTO @mytemptablevariable 
        values (@i, DATEADD(DAY, @weekfromdatedays, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @result_date)), DATEADD(DAY, @weektodatedays, @result_date))
        set @i = @i+1
        set @weekfromdatedays = @weekfromdatedays + 7
        set @weektodatedays = @weektodatedays + 7       
    end

-- Using values in week range temp table, select what week number the passed in date variable is in 

select @weeknumber = weeknumber
from @mytemptablevariable
where @refdate >= fromdate AND @refdate <= todate

-- Return the result of the function to the query or calling statement
RETURN @weeknumber

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use the below logic. I am not creating a function, just because I don't know what exactly you want from the function.

```
Declare @refDate datetime       = '2014-07-26 11:54:04.293',
        @NoWeeksforRange INT    = 6, 
        @dayName Varchar(30)    = 'Sunday'
----------------------------------------------------------------
Declare @ref int,   
        @start int              = 1
Declare @mytemptablevariable table (weeknumber INT,fromdate DATETIME,todate DATETIME)

Select  @ref = Case When @dayName = 'Sunday'    Then -1
                    When @dayName = 'Monday'    Then 5
                    When @dayName = 'Tuesday'   Then 4
                    When @dayName = 'Wednesday' Then 3
                    When @dayName = 'Thursday'  Then 2
                    When @dayName = 'friday'    Then 1
                    When @dayName = 'Saturday'  Then 0 Else 0 End

Select  @ref = Cast(@refDate As int) - (DATEPART(Weekday,@refDate)) - @ref

While @NoWeeksforRange > 0
Begin
    Insert into @mytemptablevariable
    Select  @NoWeeksforRange, 
            Cast((@ref - (7 * (@start - 1))) - 6 As datetime),
            Cast(@ref - (7 * (@start - 1)) As datetime)
    Set @NoWeeksforRange = @NoWeeksforRange - 1
    Set @start = @start + 1
End

Select  * From @mytemptablevariable order By weeknumber
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Yes that could very well be what I am looking for. I must be going down the right path as I was thinking along the lines of some sort of case statement that would decode the Day name to a number then use this as further calculation . I need to work through this and see if I can make full sense of it and compare it with my idea.

Many thanks for posting this.